# Regex in grep -E not working as expected

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I'm working on a bash shell script, which goes through a folder and eventually makes new directories based off file names.
Now I want to go through each file and strip away unwanted slashes of the path and ignore the fileextension before making a new directory.
To test this, I'm echoing my file like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

cpath=`pwd`
for file in $cpath/*;do
echo $file | grep -E '(?!.*/).+(?=\.)'
done
```

But grep filters out everything and I get no output. I worked out the regex with RegExr http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2vu6b
Negative lookahead to match the last slash and positive lookahead matching the last dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if Negative lookahead is a part of Extended RE. But you can do something like this -

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $PWD/*; do
basename "${file%.*}"
done
```

Comment: You don't even need the `echo`!

Comment: can also just do `for file in $PWD/*; do`

Comment: @SiegeX Yep!! That would be the right way of doing it. I will update the answer.

Comment: lookaheads/lookbehinds are not part of ERE. It is available in PCRE, so grep -P can be used in GNU grep.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments. Good to know I can use lookarounds for later use.